# How can I take a single element out of a boost library (e.g. shared_pointer)?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, boost-smart-ptr

I've been playing around with some Boost components, and the only one I see a direct need for in the project I'm working on is `boost::shared_ptr`.

Would it be difficult to just include the required files for `shared_ptr`, or at least just include files for the Boost smart_ptr directory in my project?  They seem to have some external dependencies on other parts of Boost - but I figure there's an easy way to just use certain components of the Boost library and I'm missing it.

If you can tell me what parts I need or point me to a good tutorial I'd be most grateful!

Comment: It is a bit unclear: do you want to copy parts of boost for your project? Why?

Comment: @UncleBens: Because Boost is a giant thing and a lot of people don't like downloading giant things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool to extract only the header you want.

```
bcp shared_ptr /foo
```

This copies `shared_ptr` and all dependencies to the directory *foo*

Answer (score -3):

You can only include the shared_ptr headers from boost like this

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

look at a basic example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/example/shared_ptr_example.cpp) or for more examples [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)

you can include nearly every part of the boost lib in this way and it has nearly no further dependencies (only for some more complex libs)

Comment: Well, bcp page says it would find 274 header dependencies for `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` - most not needed for one compiler with one configuration. I don't think it is that easy to extract libraries from boost (it sounds like OP wants to keep shared_ptr and throw away the rest).

Comment: @UncleBens Yeah, that's what I was preferably looking to do - I appreciate the suggestion though! :)

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question, which is not "How do I use #include on boost files" but "How do I determine which boost files I need to distribute for #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> to work?"